# Error when calling a function in ASP.Net (C#) from flex side

Tags: apache-flex, function, callback

I want to call a function at c# side from flex side. But I got an error as below.

> CallBack   method="handleFaultReturn"   arguments="[RPC
>   Fault faultString="Could not find a suitable method with name
>   SampleFunction" faultCode="Server.Processing" faultDetail="null"]"

Any idea?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you post the error message??

Comment: **<CallBack   method="handleFaultReturn"   arguments="[RPC Fault faultString="Could not find a suitable method with name SampleFuntion" faultCode="Server.Processing" faultDetail="null"]"/>**

Comment: there may be type miss match argument types(sending and recieving)...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it. It was due to the access modifier of the function at ASP .net. Previously it was **private**. I changed it to **public**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I got it. It was due to the access modifier of the function at ASP .net. Previously it was **private**. I changed it to **public**.